# Record management in document management project - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, records-center

For a document management project we need to implement a record management capability to a document library . 
Which template should we use?

Record centre Or document Center?

Record center has many benefits like content organizer etc & at the same time in a document center we can implement In place record management.

pl guide.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decide if you want to use in place records management or not. If not, create a record centre and route documents to the record centre.

If you want to use in place RM, then you can do that with any template, not just a document centre. Enable the "In Place Records Management" feature at the site collection level. Then you can declare records in any library in that site collection by selecting the document and then clicking "Declare Record" on the ribbon.